# Binomial probability question on cars

Tags: probability

A man is restoring ten old cars, six of them manufactured in 1955 and four of them manufactured in 1962. When he tries to start them, on average the 1955 models will start 65% of the time and the 1962 models will start 80% of the time. Find, correct to four decimal places, the probability that at any time:

**a exactly three of the 1955 models and one of the 1962 models will start**

(6C3) (0.65^3) (0.35)^3 + 4C1 (0.8) (0.2)^3

All I did was plug in the binomial probability formula for two parts and then use the addition rule of probability. I assume the guy tried to start all the cars.

(6C3) (0.65^3) (0.35)^3 comes from the fact that there are 6 1955 cars and here the random variable X is that 3 of those 1955 cars start (ie. that expression represents P(X=3).

4C1 (0.8) (0.2)^3 comes from the fact that there are 4 1962 cars and here the random variable X is that 1 of those cars start (ie. that expression represents P(X=1)

So my expression yields the answer 0.26109 but the actual answer is supposed to be 0.0060. Hmm?

Comment: Why do you "use the addition rule of probability"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You added the individual probabilities for the two types of cars, when in fact you needed to multiply them.  This is because for two independent events $A$ and $B$, $$\Pr[A \cap B] \overset{\text{ind}}{=} \Pr[A]\Pr[B];$$ that is to say, the probability that both $A$ and $B$ occur is equal to the product of the individual probabilities that each occurs.  For instance, if you roll a fair six-sided die and flip a fair coin, the probability that the you rolled a $6$ and flipped heads is
$$\Pr[\text{rolled a 6} \cap \text{flipped heads}] = \Pr[\text{rolled a 6}] \Pr[\text{flipped heads}] = \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{12}.$$

For the same reason, the probability that exactly three of the 1955 models start, *and* exactly one of the 1962 models start, must be the product of their individual event probabilities.  If $X$ is the random variable that counts the number of 1955 model cars that start, and $Y$ is the random variable that counts the number of 1962 models that start, then we are given that
$$X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n = 6, p = 0.65), \\
Y \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n = 4, p = 0.8).$$
Therefore,
$$\begin{align}
\Pr[(X = 3) \cap (Y = 1)] &\overset{\text{ind}}{=} \Pr[X = 3]\Pr[Y = 1] \\
&= \binom{6}{3} (0.65)^3 (1 - 0.65)^{6-3} \cdot \binom{4}{1} (0.8)^1 (1 - 0.8)^{4-1} \\
&\approx 0.00602857
\end{align}$$
which matches the claimed answer.

---

As a further exercise:  what would be the probability that *at least* three of the 1955 model cars start, and *at most* one of the 1962 cars start?  Write such an event in terms of the random variables $X$ and $Y$ defined above.  Then apply the independence of events to calculate the probability.

Comment: hello hero pup Happy New Years and thank you for your reply. For your further exercise, is it right if I consider it in terms of cases and then write each case in terms of x and y?

Comment: @moonriver Essentially, yes.  First, try calculating $$\Pr[Y \le 1] = \Pr[Y = 0] + \Pr[Y = 1] = \binom{4}{0} (0.8)^0 (1-0.8)^4 + \binom{4}{1} (0.8)^1 (1-0.8)^3.$$  Next, calculate $\Pr[X \ge 3]$ using the same approach.  And finally, apply the same rule for the probability of independent events.